# jquery owl carousel issue with ajaxing controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, owl-carousel

does anyone know of a work around for owl carousel so you can re initiate it after you have done an ajax get?

```
.done(function (result) {
            $(ajaxdiv).html(result);
            $("div.products").owlCarousel({
                items: 5,
                loop: true
            });
        });
```

Doesnt seem to reinitialise it.

Any help gratefully appreciated